# Query from existing worksheet values with firstname, lastname and WHERE clause needs to match on firstname and lastname

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am looking to get a query result using existing data in the where clause.  the existing data and tables to query have firstname and lastname split in to 2 fields.  I need a way to pass both fields in an array and in a single where condition.

For example, here is the worksheet of my source data I need to query on:

```
Dob         Last        First     SSN
6/6/2006    Notaperson  Billy     999880006
1/1/2001    Testing     Marco     999880001/217061866
2/2/2002    Case        Delilah   999880002
3/3/2003    Testcase    Julius    999880003
4/4/2004    Notreal     Adrianna  999880004
5/5/2005    Fake        Julianna  999880005
12/1/2017   Mars        Danielle  999880005
```

[Image of source data worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcQrd.png)

I need to query on any Dob, Any SSN and any MATCHING first and last name.
For Example:
return all rows where Dob=6/6/2006 and ssn=999880006 and FIRST/LAST=Notaperson Billy

Below is what I've written but it is returning any rows with last=Notaperson and/or any rows with first=Billy.

How can I set the where clause to search on firstname and lastname as a single data value?

'''

```
with subjects as (
Select 
    s.subject_key
    , s.dob
    , n.last
    , n.first
    , sa_cid.alias                      as cid
    , sa_cid.facility_key               as cid_facility_key
    , sa_cid.primary_aliaås             as cid_primary_alias
    , sa_cid.subject_alias_type_key     as cid_subject_alias_type_key
    , sa.alias
    , sa.facility_key
    , sa.primary_alias
    , sa.subject_alias_type_key
from subject s

inner join subject_alias sa_cid
    on sa_cid.subject_key = s.subject_key
        and sa_cid.subject_alias_type_key = 3

inner join subject_alias sa
    on sa.subject_key = s.subject_key
        and sa.subject_alias_type_key != 3      

inner join name n
    on n.name_key = s.current_name_key

WHERE 1 = 1
    and dob = ANY(
        '{6/6/2006, 1/1/2001, 2/2/2002, 3/3/2003, 4/4/2004, 5/5/2005, 12/1/2017}')
    or (
                n.last = ANY(
                '{NOTAPERSON, TESTING, CASE, TESTCASE, NOTREAL, FAKE, MARS
                }')     
                OR n.first = ANY(
                '{BILLY, MARCO, DELILAH, JULIUS, ADRIANNA, JULIANNA, DANIELLE
                }')
            )
    or sa.alias = any('{
        999880006, 999880001/217061866, 999880002, 999880003, 999880004, 999880005, 999880005}')
)

select 
    subject_key
    , dob
    , last
    , first
    , cid
    , array_agg(alias || ':' || facility_key || ':' || subject_alias_type_key) as other_alias
from subjects 
group by subject_key, dob, last, first, cid
order by cid, dob, last, first
```

'''

Comment: You did say last . . . OR  . . . first.  Try 'and'?

Comment: If anyway you hard coding that search values, just combine last_name||' '||first_name in ('David Beckham')  and search. Based on your database you need to choose the concatenation method.

Comment: Thanks David, you are right...  I got a little sloppy.  last and first is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Just picking your input, and skipping all joins, as we have no input from the other tables.
Do you mean something like this? You can put *row expressions* into an `IN()` list ...

Mind that the `ANY('{}')` expression is by no means a typical SQL syntax, while the `IN()` notation to specify a set of values (or, indeed, rows) is.

```
WITH
input(dob,last,first,ssn) AS (
          SELECT DATE '6/6/2006' ,'Notaperson','Billy'   ,'999880006'           
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/1/2001' ,'Testing'   ,'Marco'   ,'999880001/217061866'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2/2/2002' ,'Case'      ,'Delilah' ,'999880002'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '3/3/2003' ,'Testcase'  ,'Julius'  ,'999880003'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '4/4/2004' ,'Notreal'   ,'Adrianna','999880004'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '5/5/2005' ,'Fake'      ,'Julianna','999880005'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '12/1/2017','Mars'      ,'Danielle','999880005'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM input
WHERE dob IN (
  DATE '6/6/2006' 
, DATE '1/1/2001' 
, DATE '2/2/2002' 
, DATE '3/3/2003' 
, DATE '4/4/2004' 
, DATE '5/5/2005' 
, DATE '12/1/2017'
)
  OR (last,first) IN (
     ('Notaperson', 'Billy'   )
   , ('Testing'   , 'Marco'   )
   , ('Case'      , 'Delilah' )
   , ('Testcase'  , 'Julius'  )
   , ('Notreal'   , 'Adrianna')
   , ('Fake'      , 'Julianna')
   , ('Mars'      , 'Danielle')
)
-- out     dob     |    last    |  first   |         ssn        
-- out ------------+------------+----------+--------------------
-- out  2006-06-06 | Notaperson | Billy    | 999880006
-- out  2001-01-01 | Testing    | Marco    | 999880001/217061866
-- out  2002-02-02 | Case       | Delilah  | 999880002
-- out  2003-03-03 | Testcase   | Julius   | 999880003
-- out  2004-04-04 | Notreal    | Adrianna | 999880004
-- out  2005-05-05 | Fake       | Julianna | 999880005
-- out  2017-12-01 | Mars       | Danielle | 999880005
```

Comment: I believe 'marcothesane' has simplified and resolved this.  That is awesome!  I'm going to test further

Comment: Test further and can confirm @marcothesane provided the answer.